# How to Better Iterate over State in Clojure (monad?)

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, state, monads

I just wrote this code:

```
(defn parameters [transform-factory state]
  (lazy-seq (let [[r1 state] (uniform state)
                  [r2 state] (uniform state)
                  [t state] (transform-factory state)]
              (cons [t [r1 r2]] (parameters transform-factory state)))))

(defn repeated-transform [mosaic n transform-factory state]
  (reduce transform-square mosaic
    (take n (parameters transform-factory state))))
```

the `parameters` function generates a lazy sequence of values generated from the `state`, which are used to parameterise a repeated transformation of something (a "mosaic" in this case).

it seems to me that `parameters` shows a fairly common pattern which surfaces when you have some `state` that must be carried around (in this case to generate random values).  is there a name for this?

is there a better way to write the first function?  related problems can often be solved with `reduce`, which "carries along" the state, but here i have nothing to reduce.  similarly, `reductions` doesn't seem to fit.  is this a good case for a monad? (from a theoretical pov i don't see how you define a way to combine multiple instances into one, but perhaps that doesn't change the practical application - it does seem like the kind of problem monads solve elsewhere, where some state needs to be carried around).

(ps i mentioned random numbers, but i can't replace this with a solution that uses mutable state behind the scenes - as "normal" random routines do - for reasons unrelated to the question).

Comment: > (ps i mentioned random numbers, but i can't replace this with a solution that uses mutable state behind the scenes - as "normal" random routines do - for reasons unrelated to the question).

You could use a) a pseudo-random generator carrying a seed around, or b) copy the mutable state (so that its not mutable). I took this approach for the [pure mersenne twister][1] implementation.


  [1]: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64-0.2.0.3

Comment: I came here to ask the exact same question

Comment: @DonStewart - i don't understand how that would change what i am asking.  in fact, what i am doing is copying the state - that is what the `state` is above, and the source of my problems.

Comment: As far as the "pattern" is concerned, it looks like a blend of `reduce`and `map`. Reduce for threading the state through a set of functions, Map for taking the value (other then state) generated by each function invocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly look at the state monad to see if it is a good fit for you.

General guidelines to use monads are:

- Sequential execution (pipeline operations)
- Reusable modular side effect processing (ex: error handling/ logging/
  state)
- Keep your business logic clean in pure functions

Some resources on monads that I found very useful (for Clojure) are

Adam Smyczek:
Introduction to Monads (Video)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObR3qi4Guys

and 
Jim Duey:
Monads in Clojure
http://www.clojure.net/2012/02/02/Monads-in-Clojure/

Comment: thanks - i'll have a look.  was hoping this was a well-known issue but apparently not, so have the "best answer" cookie :o)

Answer (score 3):

[answering myself, since this is the best solution i've found so far]

you can rewrite the above as a fold *over the functions*.  so the functions become data, the state is the "passed through", and the function used applies each function in turn to the state and accumulates the result.

i can't see an elegant way to implement this - the function that is folded appears to be "new" and you need extra boilerplate to add/separate the state and accumulator - so i wrapped the whole process in a function called `fold-over`.  the [source is here](https://github.com/andrewcooke/clojure-lab/blob/master/src/org/acooke/lab/state.clj#L20) and [an example of the function in use is here](https://github.com/andrewcooke/clojure-lab/blob/master/test/org/acooke/lab/state-test.clj#L40).

Comment: this feels close to me. It seems like maybe that this approach with some macros could turn in into a folding `let`, and maybe that would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Something you should check into is `->` and `->>`, the threading macros.

Instead of code like this:

```
(let [state (dosomething state)
      state (dosomethingelse state)
      state (dolastthing state)]
    state)
```

You can write:

```
(-> state (dosomething) (dosomethingelse) (dolasttthing))
```

which "threads" state through the functions, eventually returning it.

Now, your code doesn't exactly follow what I've written. The way I imagine it could follow it was if your functions took and returned hashmaps. i.e. (uniform state) could return `{:state state-val :r1 r1-val}`.

Then you could rewrite your code like this:

```
(->> {:state state} (merge uniform) (merge uniform) (transform-factory))
```

Much nicer! :)